# NFC reader apache cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to read nfc card with phonegap nfc ( [Tutorial phonegap](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/doc/GettingStartedCLI.md) ) but the event is not launched

this is the code of the index.js

```
 onDeviceReady: function() {
     app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

// Read NDEF formatted NFC Tags
nfc.addNdefListener (
    function (nfcEvent) {
        var tag = nfcEvent.tag,
            ndefMessage = tag.ndefMessage;

        // dump the raw json of the message
        // note: real code will need to decode
        // the payload from each record
        alert(JSON.stringify(ndefMessage));

        // assuming the first record in the message has
        // a payload that can be converted to a string.
        alert(nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(3));
    },
    function () { // success callback
        alert("Waiting for NDEF tag");
    },
    function (error) { // error callback
        alert("Error adding NDEF listener " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
},
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you trying to read with the app opened? Do you have any output in the console or alerts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved with  **nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener**  instead of nfc.addNdefListener